# Laravel 5.1 > split nested lazy loading

Tags: nested, laravel-5, lazy-loading

Is it possible to split a nested lazy loading method?

I´ve got

```
$this->user->load('latestConversations.latestMessage.user')
```

I´d also like to load all Users assigned to latestConversations so something like this would be nice:

```
$this->user->load('latestConversations.['users', 'latestMessage.user']')
```

Here is a workaround

```
$this->user->load('latestConversations.latestMessage.user')
$this->user->load('latestConversations.users')
```

But then latestConversations are queried two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave the parentheses on the relation method you can just add on whatever you want to the query, and then manually set the relation using `setRelation()`. I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
$latestConversations = $this->user
                            ->latestConversations()
                            ->with('latestMessage.user', 'users')
                            ->get();
$this->user->setRelation('latestConversations', $latestConversations);

// then you should be able to just access it normally:
return $this->user->latestConversations;
```

Comment: worked like a charm. I even hadn´t to use setRelation because latestConversations was still related inside the User Model via belongsToMany(). Thanks mate.